# PC shuts down in specific games

Tags: hardware-failure, shutdown, desktop-computer

My pc just turns off when I reach certain spots of certain games. It does not shut down, but simply goes out and then starts up again automatically.
I have had this behavior so far in Red Dead Redemption 2 at various points, but especially when you reach Saint Denis. In Phasmaphobia when I play Karty Asylum and leave the truck and in Assassin's Creed Odyssey as soon as I start a new game.
In all three cases it appears as if the error always occurs in a very similar place. As if something were being loaded that caused the computer to crash.

At first I assumed the part was overheated. However, all measurements showed that shortly before the crash all sensors were between 54 ° C and a maximum of 62 ° C. So actually no temperature where I would expect such behavior.
I then went through the hard drive and started the games from another hard drive. However, the behavior remained the same.

I have already replaced the RAM and the GPU. The error still occurred.

My system looks like this:

- System: MS-7A38
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-core, 3800 MHz
- RAM: G.SKILL Value DDR4 2400 C15 4x8GB
- OS: Windows 10 Home
- Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 Super

Does anyone have any idea what else I could check? I'm not getting the impression that it's just a hardware failure.

Comment: Restarting means a BSoD happens but it happens so quickly that you don't see the code. The EventLog will show you the BSoD code. You will want to research that. Also BSoD's are common in cracked games due to a bad crack. Not saying that is the case with you, but if that is the case, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: What about the psu?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LPChip. There are logs. But the event ID is 6008 and seems to be very unspecific.

Comment: Its common in Windows 10, which is not respected anywhere. Use Windows 7. It also does seem like an overpressure issue of the hardware, meaning some component can't bare the load and shuts down. Probably the video card or processor like written in the answer.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom I'm not sure which overpressure issue you mean. My system doesn't overheat and has enough PSU. The entire system should easily render a game like the three I named.

Comment: If this is not a generic issue, that means its a virus or hardware failure. In order for the PC to shut down at a higher load, then something is overloading it. It can be a short circuit or other. Its best to use some benchmark software and do a stress test. This will tell us if its the game or the high load.

Comment: I did a couple benchmark tests. None of them found an issue and ranked the hardware components high. UserBenchmark for example placed it on 91%. That's why I don't think it's a hardware issue. Could be some drivers conflict in my eyes since the shut down doesn't seem to be randomly. Overloading issues would be at random places with just much rendering. But these spots seem to render something specific I couldn't figure out yet.

Comment: Have you tried a new pcie slot?

Comment: If you are using Windows 10, install the latest updates and all Visual reistributables from 2008 to 2017, x32 and x64 versions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good possibility your PSU isn't up to the task of powering the GPU in that particular spot.

try lowering your GPU settings quite a bit and you'll see if it works, old PSU's or damaged ones from electric issues like blackouts and unstable power can fail to provide enough power to the machine when the GPU demands a lot.

a 750w PSU is good enough for a GTX 2060

Comment: I have a 600w PSU but I used a PSU-calculator which says a 450W would be enough. So I'm already over that with my 600w.

Comment: I'm not sure that's an accurate calculator, or maybe your data wasn't entered correctly, a 600w can't run my pc, I have an i7 9700k 32gb ram, rtx 2070, I had to switch to a 750.

Comment: I rechecked it with another calculator and someone who checked the components himself. I mean I still could try, since the behavior would make sense. But I can't find any hint to that. I'm monitoring the power while playing and I can't see any irregular behavior there.

Comment: Did you take into account all the usb devices? cooling? and any other devices in there?